# Graphing with Java Swing - Threading and MSSQL

Tags: java, swing, mssql-jdbc

I have written a custom graphing class in java swing that will pull data from mssql server every 5 minutes and plot it for me. Here is my architecture

TimerGraph <-- DataSource (MSSQL) <-- MSSQLManager  <-- main

My TimerGraph will tell the DataSource when to request new data point.

My MSSQLDataSource has query specific variables that it communicates to the MSSQLManager to execute queries

My MSSQLManager will connect to database and execute queries for me.

So my problem is scalability, when I need to graph multiple data points from the same database but with different variables. I have implemented it so that each MSSQLDataSource holds a reference to the same MSSQLManager connection so that the respective query can be executed on the same DB connection.

When my timers kick off and request a new point from each datasource, and then that datasource goes and requests to execute query from it's referenced db connection, only 1 call is actually getting made. (When there should be about ~20 or so)...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpotCheck sc = new SpotCheck();
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(sc);
}
```

My main app has a method run() that executes on separate thread and instantiates my TimerGraphs (I'm using swing timers btw). I have used CardLayouts to display the proper graph based on the selected combobox item. Do swing timers actionListeners still get executed if the JPanel is not visible in the current CardLayout? If not, is it possible to make them? Or am I having some kind of threading issue.

Thanks

Comment: `Do swing timers actionListeners still get executed if the JPanel is not visible in the current CardLayout?` Easy enough to check. Just add a System.out.println(..) statement to your code and see what happens.

Comment: I don't know if it's my timers that are failing or if it's a threading issue. println is not showing anything except for the last Timer that I started. I have about 20 timers hitting my MSSQLManager all at the same time interval

Comment: A Timer has no sense of whether a panel is visible or not. So I would guess it is a threading issue. Each call to the Database should be done using a separate Thread, not a Swing Timer. If all the database calls are done on the Event Dispatch Thread then the GUI will not be able to respond. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) for more information.